# window.XMLHttpRequest undefined

Tags: node.js, angular

I created a node.js app to parse `angular2`'s HTML AST and Typescript AST in order to extract data.

To do this, I need to import `@angular/compiler` and thus `@angular/core`, which requires a `peerDependency` of `zone.js@^0.6.21`.

Problem is that zone.js seems to be a bit broken with node.js application at loading time:

```
<my-project>/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1286
var openNative = patchMethod(window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'open', function () { return function (self, args) {
                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at patchXHR (<my-project>/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1286:55)
at <my-project>/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1253:1
at Zone.Zone.zoneSpec._properties (<my-project>/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:9:68)
at Object.<anonymous> (<my-project>/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:12:2)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
```

Before I upgraded to `angular2 final`, I was using `angular 2.0.0-rc.1` and it requires `zone.js@ ^0.6.6`, which worked fine.

#### Already tried

- Removing `zone.js`, but impossible because it breaks the code.
- Updating to `zone.js@0.6.25`, still same exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you import `zone-node` not `zone`:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
```